# How to import products from Woo-commerce to Yatego shopping?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, export-to-csv

I have site in `WordPress` and I want to import products from my `Woo-commerce shop` into the `Yatego shopping` using CSV format.

I have tried the following plugins with `CSV format` but that cannot supporting into `Yatego importer`

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-csvimport/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/webappick-product-feed-for-woocommerce/installation/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/purple-xmls-google-product-feed-for-woocommerce/

I'm stuck with this now, does any one can help me here? Thanks for your time and help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-csvimport/ Woocommerce csv import tool to export the csv file of all the products.

Then you need to convert the csv file into the yatelo's custom csv format as per yatego's example and then import the file into the yatego's importer.

Also please follow the instructions from yatego's csv format standards.